# Why does this mapped/conditional type behave differently when inferring the type of "this" vs receiving it explicitly?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.8

Consider the following code, which uses TypeScript language features [introduced in v2.8](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html) (conditional types):

```
type P<TObject, TPropertySuperType> = {
    [K in keyof TObject]: TObject[K] extends TPropertySuperType ? K : never;
}[keyof TObject];

function g<
    T,
    K extends keyof Pick<T, P<T, string>>
    >(obj: T, prop: K): void { }

class C {
    public alpha: string;
    public beta: number;

    public f(): void {
        g(this, "alpha"); // <-- does not compile!
        g(this, "beta");

        g<C, "alpha">(this, "alpha");
        g<C, "beta">(this, "beta");

        g(new C(), "alpha");
        g(new C(), "beta");

        this.g2("alpha");
        this.g2("beta");

        this.g2<"alpha">("alpha");
        this.g2<"beta">("beta");
    }

    public g2<
        K extends keyof Pick<C, P<C, string>>
        >(prop: K) { }
}
```

The idea behind the type `P` is that it selects the *names* of the properties of `TObject` that satisfy the constraint that the *type* of the property extends `TPropertySuperType`. The functions `g` and `g2` then use the type `P` in a type parameter constraint, such that:

- You can only call `g` when the `prop` parameter is the name of a `extends string`-typed property of `obj`
- You can only call `g2` when the `prop` parameter is the name of a `extends string`-typed property of `C`.

Here, because `C.alpha` is of type `string` and `C.beta` is of type `number`, I would expect all five invocations of `g`/`g2` with `prop === "alpha"` to compile, and all five invocations with `prop === "beta"` *not* to compile.

However, the invocation `g(this, "alpha")` does *not* compile, as you can see if you paste this code into [the TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html). The error is:

```
Argument of type '"alpha"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'this[keyof this] extends string ? keyof this : never'.
```

Why does this particular invocation fail? I'm guessing it has something to do with how TypeScript infers the type of `this`, but the details are fuzzy to me.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with arthem the most likely culprit is polymorphic `this`. While obvious the type of `this` will be polymorphic `this`. While you can say for sure `C['alpha']` is of type `string`, for `this['alpha']` you can't say that, all you can say is that `this['alpha'] extends string` which is a more complicated relation for the compiler to follow. Not sure if this analogy helps, but polymorphic `this` acts like a hidden type parameter to the class, and using it is subject to similar limitations. For example, inside `g` the type of `obj['prop']` is not known to be `string` again because of limitations of what can be said for generic type parameters:

```
function g<
    T,
    K extends keyof Pick<T, P<T, string>>
    >(obj: T, prop: K): void {  obj[prop].charAt(0) /*error*/}
```

While the above is speculation (and I'll admit a bit fuzzy), the solution that solves the error above will solve the issue with `this` namely to put our constraint that only `string` keys can be passed in in a different way.

```
function g3<
    K extends string | number | symbol,
    T extends Record<K, string>
    >(obj: T, prop: K): void {   obj[prop].charAt(0) /* ok*/ }

class C {
    public alpha!: string;
    public beta!: number;

    public f(): void {
        g3(this, "alpha"); // also ok as expected
        g3(this, "beta"); //not ok
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell without looking at the compiler sources, but one thing is clear: `this` inside `C` does not have type `C`, based on the observation that error goes away if you add type assertion `this as C`:

```
class C {
    public alpha: string;
    public beta: number;

    public f(): void {
        g(this as C, "alpha"); // ok
```

The type `this[keyof this]` spelled out in the error message in place for `TObject[K]` hints at `this` being ["polymorphic this"](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#polymorphic-this-types) type - the type that represents all possible subtypes of `C`.

I don't know what causes `this` to be treated as polymorphic here (maybe it's always assumed to be polymorphic), but it has an unfortunate consequence that set of its keys is not statically known.

Although it can be proven that even with polymorphic this, `"alpha"` will always be among its keys and `this["alpha"]` type will be compatible with `string`, as it's declared in `C`, the compiler does not follow the necessary logic, and just plays it safe - "if it's not statically known it's incompatible".